# How to use React.forwardRef() with own ref in the component?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref, react-forwardref

**Task**
I'm trying to use `React.forwardRef()` and in the same time use `React.useRef()` in a component.

**Problem**
I can use **either** only `myOwnRef` **or** `ref` from forwardRef prop. So, I have no idea how to use them together.
Example code:

```js
interface IExampleInputProps {
    value: string,
    onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}
const ExampleInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement | null, IExampleInputProps>(({value, onChange}, ref) => { // can't to use "ref" parameter
    const myOwnRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

    return <input ref={el => {
        myOwnRef.current = el; // => OK
        if (ref) { // trying to use the ref passed from the forwardRef function
            ref.current = el; // => ERROR
        }
    }} value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
})
```

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To access a ref while also forwarding it, it is simpler to do the following:

- Attach a ref created inside the component to the element.
- Call the [`useImperativeHandle`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle) hook on the outer ref (which is being forwarded to) and pass a function that returns the `current` property of the inner ref, which is the value that will be set to the `current` property of the outer ref.

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef } from 'react';
const MyComponent = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, IExampleInputProps>(({value, onChange}, outerRef) => {
    const innerRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    useImperativeHandle(outerRef, () => innerRef.current!, []);
    // remember to list any dependencies of the function that returns the ref value, similar to useEffect
    return <input ref={innerRef} value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
});
```

Comment: Why does the innerRef.current has a ! sign at the end?

Comment: @mortadelo That's for TypeScript (non-null assertion). You should remove it if you're not using TypeScript.